# ASP.NET MVC 6 Project cannot find DNX Run time

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, dnx, dnvm

When I try to build the project the error I get is as follows..

```
The Dnx Runtime package needs to be installed. See output window for more details
```

I have tried running both

```
dnvm upgrade
dnvm upgrade -r CoreClr
```

And when I run

```
dnvm list
```

I can see the run time installed which matches my project properties.
 I have also tried the solution outlined here;

```
http://www.sblackler.net/2015/05/02/Up-And-Running-With-DNX-DNVM-DNU/
```

Anyone have any ideas what else I can try? Is there a way to explicitly point my project to the run time in the .dnx folder of my

```
C:\Users\<Username>\.dnx
```

folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a bit late, but better late than never ;)

clean up your dnx runtimes in `C:\Users\USERNAME\.dnx`  and run `dnvm upgrade`. This should reinstall the latest runtimes. Or just use `dnvm install <version>` to install the ones you require.

Next, make sure your project references the right dnx runtime package in global.json depending on your preferences.

```
"sdk": {
  "version": "1.0.0-beta7",
  "runtime": "clr",
  "architecture": "x86"
}
```

Check project properties to point to the specific runtime of your choice.

[image: Project Properties]

*Also try and keep your dependencies in the same beta version to avoid anomalies.*

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the command line, you need to make sure that you also do `dnvm use <version/label>`.

On dnvm list, you'll see labels to the right, or you can use a specific version.

`dnvm use default` will use the default label.

`dnvm use 1.0.0-beta4` will use the beta4 runtime specifically.  (assuming you have it installed).